# Why is 400030 not giving out the logic that its greater than 400000?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a code to echo "limit reached" if **A** is greater than **B.** But if A is 400030 and B is 400000 it shows no output. If A is further greater than that, let say 400060 or any number higher than that, it shows the output.. Please how do I explain that? The code snippet to demonstrate what I mean is....

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
 
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo ("<script>location.href='../clogin/'</script>");
    die();
}
   
if(isset($_POST['transfer'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    $transAmount = $_POST['transAmount'];
    $totalTrans = $transAmount + 30;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username = ?";
    
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if(!$result) {
        die('ERROR:' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $count =  $result->num_rows;
 
     if($count == 1) {  
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $accTrans = $totalTrans + $row['dailyTrans'];
     
            $sql2 = "UPDATE customer set dailyTrans=? WHERE  username=?"; 
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql2); 
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $accTrans,$username);
            $stmt->execute();
            if(!$stmt) {
                die('network problem');
            }
     
            if($row['dailyTrans'] >= $row['dailyLimit'])  {
                echo '<script>swal.fire("FAILED!!", "<strong>You have reached the total amount you can send per day.</strong><hr><br/><i>Visit your bank to increase transfer limit.</i>", "error");
    
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = "transfer1.php";}
                    , 1700);
                </script>'; 
                //exit(); 
            } else {
                echo"";  
            }
        }//while loop
    }//count
}//submit
?>
```

My question Summary Again

The value for `$row['dailyTrans'] is 400030` and the value of `$row['dailyLimit'] is 400000`

This is suppose to echo out the error  but fails... if `$row['dailyTrans']` is greater than 400030, it echoes out. What is the logic behind that?.

Please be nice with your comments as usual. Thanks . Both Value are integers!!

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Owk tanx. But then, I think the question can still be answered?? @ riggsfolly

Comment: Put an `echo "dailyTrans = $row[dailyTrans] and  dailyLimit = $row[dailyLimit]";` just after your IF test, do you see the output?

Comment: Is this ALL the code in this script?

Comment: That's all the code except for the HTML form which I don't think its neccesary. I suppose?

Comment: It seems a bit pointless to do the limit check **after** updating the record.

Comment: Do you link to the SWAL javascript library somewhere?

Comment: Using the CDN. The thing is. The code works well juss for the fact that at value  **400030** it doesn't show the output which means its seeing it as lesser than 400000 according to the code

Comment: Sorry, but cannot reproduce the behaviour, works for me as expected.

Comment: Did you try the `echo` I suggested

Comment: Hurh!! What could be now be the issue ?

Comment: Yes. The echo worked @riggsfolly. It displayed d values

Comment: So the issue is in the javascript stuff

Comment: Have you checked the Developer Tools console for JS Errors (F12 in the browser)

Comment: Let me explain well. The JavaScript alert works if the value is above **400030**  e.g **40060 and above**. But at exactly **400030** it get blank denoting that its less than limit according to what I want.. But is 400030 less than 400000??

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are adding `$_POST['transAmount']` after querying the database for the user.

To get the current dailyTrans you will need to either

- Select from customer again
  (fetching the updated dailyTrans)

  OR
- compare dailyLimit to `$accTrans` ::
  (`if ($accTrans >= $row['dailyLimit'])`

Comment: with that said, the update should probably be in the else statement :P

Comment: Cool, make in the answer! 